# How to display data from database into html table using PHP

Tags: php

I want to get data from database and show them in a table using contacts.php file. I have separated project in few files and there is an error in my codes.Here is my codes:-
1. index.php

```
<html>
<head><meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
require_once 'controller/ContactsController.php';
$controller = new ContactsController();
$controller -> listContacts();
?>
</body></html>
```

2.ContactsController.php

```
<?
require_once 'model/ContactsServices.php';
class ContactsController {
public function __construct() {
    $this->contactsService = new ContactsService();
}
public function listContacts() {
    //get all the details using : getAllContacts();
    $list1 = $this->contactsService-> getAllContacts();
    include 'view/contacts.php';
}
}
```

3.ContactServices.php

```
<?
require_once 'model/ContactsGateway.php';
class ContactsService {
public function __construct () {
    $this->contactsGateway = new ContactsGateway();
}
private function openDb() {
    //Connection to the data base
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "contacts";
    $server = "localhost";
    $conn = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
    if(!$conn){
        die("could not connect: ". mysql_error());
    }
    //select database
    $select_Db = mysql_select_db($database, $conn); 
}
private function closeDb() {
    //close the data base
    mysql_close($conn);
}
public function getAllContacts() {
    //open database
    $this->openDb();
    //select all detail :: selectAll(....);
    $list = $this->contactsGateway->selectAll();
}
}
?>
```

4.ContctsGateway.php

```
   <?
    class ContactsGateway {
    public function selectAll() {
        //query to get the detail
        $sql =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list");
    }
    }
    ?>
```

5.Contacts.php

```
<table border = "1">
<thead>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Phone</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>Address</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
require_once 'model/ContactsServices.php';
$service = new ContactsService();
$service -> getAllContacts();
    $name = 'Name';
    $phone = 'Phone';
    $add = 'Address';
    $email = 'Email';
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){echo 3;
        echo
        "<tr>
            <td>{$rows['name']}</td>
            <td>{$rows['phone']}</td>
            <td>{$rows['email']}</td>
            <td>{$rows['add']}</td>
        </tr>\n";       
    }       
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

When I try this code it only gave the table headers with an error. The error saying $sql variable is undefiened in contacts.php file. I already define in contactsGateway.php and inherit to contacts.php. what is the reason for this and is there any other way to do this?

Comment: So what's going wrong?

Comment: change SELECT * list to SELECT * FROM list

Comment: I have correct that but it still gave the same error.

Comment: Please note that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and as of php 7.0 the extension has been removed. You should learn to use either PDO or MySQLi and learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Answer (score 3):

It seems your SQL query is invalid.

```
SELECT * list
```

Should Be:

```
SELECT * FROM list
```

Also, in the case of using the direct MySQL functions (Which are deprecated as of PHP 5.5, and removed in PHP 7, by the way)  you can use `mysql_error()` if the result of the `mysql_query()` funciton is equal to -1.

For Example:

```
$sql =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list") or die( mysql_error() );
```

Will stop your script on error, and display the mysql error information.

Comment: Thanks for the Edit @Qirel I didn't have the PHP version numbers readily available.

Comment: No problem :) Was a good answer you posted!

Comment: I have fix the error in my query but it is still happen the same error. When I run my script it says "Undefined variable: sql in contacts.php"

Comment: It looks like you are running into a Variable scope Issue now.  You create the $sql variables in the ContactsGateway.php function selectAll but then you end the function (and in essence lose the value(s) stored in the $sql variable within that scope.

If you wish it to "persist" and access it from other scripts, consider making it a class scope variable:

    class ContactsGateway {
        public $sql;
    }

And then setting the value to that in your selectAll function:

    $this->sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list");

Then you can access in Contacts.php:

    ContactGateway->sql;